# is there a Python Equivalent to Memcpy

Tags: python, c, memcpy

I am trying to port some C Code but I am really stuck cause of the use of memcpy I tried with ctypes (did not work). I am hoping to find a python way of using an equivalent function of memcpy

Any ideas

Here is an example of the C Code I am trying to port

```
i = l + 5;
t = htons(atoi(port));
memcpy((buf+i), &t, 2);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Show your python code.

Comment: That appears to be socket related code. The Python [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) library does a lot of that stuff for you, so you don't have to worry about using `htons()` etc in Python code. So it's hard to say without seeing more of your C code.

Comment: Very, very rarely do you want to do a direct line-by-line transcoding.  This is inefficient and fails to leverage the strengths of the new language.

Comment: I would be asking what @marcin is - what is it that you're trying to do... what's the end goal for instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost certainly don't need to call `htons` and then copy the 2 bytes into a buffer—see Keith's answer for why.

However, if you *do* need to do this (maybe you're crafting IP packets to compare to captured wire packets as a test or something?), you can.

First, if you're using a `bytearray` (or anything else that meets the writable buffer protocol), you just use normal `list`-style slice assignment:

```
# like C's memcpy(buf+i, foo, 2)
buf[i:i+2] = foo
```

You don't have that two-byte string `foo`; you have a short integer. In C, you can turn that into a pointer to two bytes just by using the `&` operator to get its address, but Python can't do that. Fortunately, there's a standard library module called [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) designed for exactly this kind of thing:

```
t = socket.htons(int(port))
buf[i:i+2] = struct.pack('h', t)
```

Or, because `struct` can handle endianness for you:

```
t = int(port)
buf[i:i+2] = struct.pack('!h', t)
```

However, often you don't even need the buffer copying; you can define the entire structure all at once inside `struct`. For example, if you're trying to pack an IP address and port into a 6-byte array, you could do this:

```
buf = bytearray(6)
i = 0
addrbytes = [int(part) for part in addr.split('.')]
buf[i:i+4] = struct.pack('4B', addrbytes[0], addrbytes[1], addrbytes[2], addrbytes[3])
i += 4
portshort = int(port)
buf[i:i+2] = struct.pack('!h', portshort)
```

But this is much simpler:

```
addrbytes = [int(part) for part in addr.split('.')]
portshort = int(port)
buf = struct.pack('!4Bh', addrbytes[0], addrbytes[1], addrbytes[2], addrbytes[3], portshort)
```

I've just defined a structure that's in network order, with four bytes followed by a short, and packed my data into it.

One last thing to mention: If you really want to deal with C-style variables using C-style code, the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module is another option. It's made specifically for interacting with C code, so in general it's pretty low-level (and the only module in the standard library that lets you segfault your code), but it let you build some nice mid-level stuff that looks a little more like C:

```
class ADDRPORT(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("addr", ctypes.c_char*4),
                ("port", ctypes.c_short)]

addrport = ADDRPORT(addrbytes, portshort)
```

Since your C code is progressively filling up a buffer, rather than setting elements of a `struct`, this probably isn't what you want. But it's worth being aware of, because it probably will be what you want at some point.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are trying to get a port number from user input or a string.

In Python:

```
port = int(port)
```

Then you can pass that directly to a socket instantiation:

```
socket = socket.socket(("127.0.0.1", port))
```

Python does the `htons` translation for you. You only need to supply an address to a socket (in the case of TCP) as a tuple of a string and integer.

Comment: Unless he's trying to, e.g., craft raw IP packets instead of just creating a socket, this is the right answer.